# Python - Pass subprocess handler to use from another script

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, handler

I'm struggling with Python subrpocess and cannot dip into any solution.

What I'm trying to do:

Module_A.py:

```
while True:
    # get the input from quee/pipe
    # then execute appropriate function
    if (received termination command):
        break
```

Module_B.py

```
# this module launches Module_A as subrpocess and exits, sth. like:
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "producer.py "])
```

Module_C.py

```
# This module is launched after Module_B is finished.
# This module communicate with Module_A and is sending commands
```

So, the main difficulty is how to pass the "proc" handler from Module_B.py to Module_C.py, to be able to communicate with Module_A.py.

Any hints?

Comment: why can't you merge Module_B.py with Module_C.py ? this seems to be the best solution to this problem, maybe module_C can import Module_B

Comment: a more complicated solution is using local sockets, but in almost all cases this is unjustified.

Comment: Those modules are to be used with external test sequencer and manage some SSH session. Module A starts measurement, and then test sequencer from time to time wants to get the current measurement analysis from background thread using requests (module C)

Comment: For me what seems to be missing is how to get the subprocess handle/reference to be able to communicate with

Comment: this seems like what local sockets are made for, while you can obviously grab the in/out fids from the OS, and open them , this will be very OS specific and in a lot of times buggy.

Comment: anyway this question will never get any answer because it has no useful information about the problem, you have to post an example of how the first and 3rd file looks like, in runnable python code or explain the problem in more detail such that it can be reproduced.